# How to consume/parse an error returned by ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx), I can create an error response in my ApiController, that provides useful information to the client, like this:

```
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("Contact {0} not found.", id)));
```

... and the client will receive an "object" containing the error details along with the (in this example) 404 status:

```
{
     "Message": "Contact 22 not found.",
     "MessageDetail": "<other info - not always present>"
}
```

(I don't think that `MessageDetail` is appropriate in this example, and so would probably not be included, but under other circumstances it might be - see the blog post).

Sounds great, but how should my C# client-side application *consume* this on the client side? I made a request, I was expecting a JSON-encoded `Contact` object in response, but instead I got a different type of object.

Because the response code indicated a failure, then I guess I know not to expect the `Contact` object, and to look instead for this error object. But given that not every error will return one of these, and also given that the `MessageDetail` member may or may not be present, how do I go about parsing the response? (Note: in my scenario, it'll be JSON-encoded, and I'm using JSON.NET on the client side).

If the object was of a well-known type, then I could just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`, but I don't think there's a pre-defined type, and if I create my own class what do I do about the optional `MessageDetail` member?

I'm not very familiar with processing JSON, so this may be obvious to those who are - in which case all advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpError is deserializable from client side. You can use it to read the data from error response.

Comment: +1 HttpError is the well-known type you are after. Some more info here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx

Comment: That's the same link as in my question! :-)

Comment: The problem for me is that HttpError is in System.Net.Http, which isn't available to my client-side project... I just created a copy of it with the relevant members.